# Mail receives delay issue in WP

Tags: wordpress, email, notifications

I have used default WordPress wp-mail functions to send mail notification

The issue is after submitting the forms or any other notification mail is received with some delay.

SMTP mail functionality also tried with [wp-mail plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-mail-smtp/) but no improvement. what is this cause of delay of mail functions.

Note :  There is any server dependency in mail functionality, because its little faster in our dev server then live server

Comment: Please review [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). You haven't included nearly enough information for us to help - we are not mind readers! Your question should include a clear outline of your *specific* coding-related issue, a summary of what you have already tried and the relevant code in a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), so we might be able to help.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend uses this wp smtp plugin. https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-mail-smtp/

In my opinion you have to set up properly the outgoing email address to receive the emails on time or avoid emails spam issue.

Regards.
Ed.